# display image with image details

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, image, repeater

i am doing a project on visual studios 2010 to display all latest images that has been added to the database. I am currently using a repeater control to allow the user to get all the latest images from the database. I am using an image button to display the images. Once the user clicks on an image button, it should bring them to another page that display the image in a image control with the image name.. I am not sure on how to do this as i am new to using repeater control. can someone help me? provide me with example codes please.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

you may get started from ExiF, google it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the repeater's ItemCommand on which you can redirect the user to another control. The following links may help you:

[MSDN Repeater ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx?ppud=4)

[Repeater Item Command](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-Repeater-OnItemCommand-Event-using-C-sharp.aspx)